# Can't control screen brightness on saucy on Acer Aspire 5755 and Acer Aspire V3-571G

Tags: 13.10, brightness

I can't control the screen brightness in Ubuntu 13.10. I tried the way that worked for me on 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

but it doesn't work on 13.10.

My laptop is an Acer Aspire V3-571G (it's similar to Acer 5755).

Comment: What is the model of the laptop ? some laptops have brightness settings on the f-keys using the fn key

Comment: Acer Aspire V3-571G (it is very similar to 5755 too)

Comment: @HOS Did you got any solution?If so, please post how it was done.     also have same issue.

Comment: I got it working on Acer Apire 5755 by editing /etc/default/grub and changing to this 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor". I had to restart the system after that. sudo update-grub did not worked.